# In PL/SQL can I pass a value from anonymous block into the calling program

Tags: plsql

For example I have a loop that is calling an anonymous block to do an action and as a result of that action a value is retrieved. Can I pass that value to the main program?

```
PROCEDURE MY_PROCEDURE
    IS
        my_id NUMBER;
    BEGIN
        FOR i IN 1..v_tab.COUNT LOOP
            IF v_tab(i).status = 'NEW' THEN

                DECLARE
                    v_row  my_table1%ROWTYPE;             

                BEGIN
                   someprocedure(var1 => v_tab(i).field1,
                                 var2 => v_tab(i).status,
                                 id    => my_id  -- OUT PARAMETER 
                                 );

                END;
            ELSE
                my_id := v_tab(i).id;
                ..... do something else
            END IF;
            --other steps performed here, utilizing my_id
        END LOOP;

        -- other steps performed here  
END MY_PROCEDURE;
```

The v_tab is defined as follows:

```
TYPE v_record IS RECORD
(
   id NUMBER,
   field1 VARCHAR2(50),
   status VARCHAR2(10)
);

TYPE v_tab_type IS TABLE OF v_record;

v_tab  v_tab_type;
```

Comment: Anonymous block is a standalone SQL statement and it cannot exist as part of some outer PL/SQL code (by definition). You may structure your code in any way you need and use nested `begin ... end;` statement which will have an access to the outer scope. It's easy to test by yourself: https://dbfiddle.uk/ldrGw0t3

Comment: @astentx an anonymous block is a PL/SQL code block that hasn't been assigned a name. You can absolutely have an anonymous block within a procedure, although I would argue that if you do that, you should be pulling it out into its own procedure.

Comment: @Boneist This is not my interpretation, but a definition: see [Index in PL/SQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/book-index.html#A). *You can submit a block to an interactive tool (such as SQL\*Plus or Enterprise Manager) or embed it in an Oracle Precompiler or OCI program. The interactive tool or program runs the block one time. The block is not stored in the database, and for that reason, it is called an **anonymous block** (even if it has a label).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is really about the scope of your variables.

When you declare a variable in the declaration portion of a procedure/function/package/anonymous block, that variable is accessible over the entirety of that procedure/function/package/anonymous block.

For example, say you have a package that looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE variable_scope_pkg
  gv_global_public VARCHAR2(1);

  PROCEDURE p1 (in_param1 VARCHAR2,
                out_param1 VARCHAR2);
END variable_scope_pkg;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY variable_scope_pkg
  gv_global_private VARCHAR2(1);

  PROCEDURE p1 (in_param1 VARCHAR2,
                out_param1 VARCHAR2)
  IS
    v_local VARCHAR2(1);
  BEGIN
  
    DECLARE
      v_sub_local VARCHAR2(1);
    BEGIN
      out_param1 := v_local || v_sub_local;
    END;
  
  END;
  
END variable_scope_pkg;
/
```

The `gv_global_public` variable defined in the package scope is available to be set or read by any code which has execute privileges on the package, including code inside the package itself. The `gv_global_private` variable defined in the package body is available to be set or read only by code within the package.

The `p1` parameters and `v_local variable` are available to be set/read by any code within the `p1` procedure, but the `v_sub_local` variable is only available to be set/read by any code within the anonymous block.

So, the answer to your question of "can I pass a value from anonymous block into the calling program?" is yes, but you must store the value in a variable that is within the scope of the calling program.

On a separate note, if you've got a nested anonymous block inside a procedure, you should consider whether it's absolutely necessary. Perhaps you should be pulling the anonymous block into its own procedure/function and then passing the values around via parameters.